# LLDB Floating point values displayed incorrectly unless printf is used

Tags: c, floating-point, lldb

I am trying to debug a program using a coredump.
But I am having trouble getting LLDB to print flating point variables correctly.

Here is an example of a debugging session:

```
(lldb) run
...
(lldb) fr v
(float) sword_v_10 = 0.200000003   <- This is incorrect.
(float) sword_v_4 = 4.69999981 <- This is also incorrect.
(lldb) e printf("%f %f\n", sword_v_10, sword_v_4)
0.200000 4.700000 <- These are the correct value.
(int) $2 = 18
```

In the example above, I ran the program in the debugger so I was able to call `printf`.
However, when simply using coredumps I am unable to use `printf`.
So I was wondering if there was any way to display floating point variables correctly when I use the `frame variable` command.

Comment: The values are not incorrect. LLDB is showing you the true values with more precision, while the default six digits after the decimal point of `%f` is not enough to show them. (The LLDB display is still not enough to see the full value, but it may be enough to uniquely distinguish it among the values representable in the `float` format.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are correct. I went back and tried to parse the values that lldb was showing using `float f; std::istream >> f;` Then printing it with `std::cout << f;` showed the same representation as `printf`. Thanks!